# Multiple changes in web.config in wix installer

Tags: xml, wix, windows-installer

I am working on wix installer and wanna modify connection string and some appsetting in web.config file of my web application.
i am using util:XmlFile for modification.
but when i run the installer, modification is only applied to connection string.

```
<Property Id="DB_USER" Value="sa"/>
<Property Id="DB_PASSWORD" Value="sa"/>
<Property Id="DB_SERVER" Value="LOCAL"/>
<Property Id="DB_DATABASE" Value="MailboxMigration_DB"/>

<Property Id="SMTP_port" />
<Property Id="SMTP_server" />
<Property Id="Email_Address" />
<Property Id="Email_Pass" />
```

after that i am setting the properties in dialog boxes.
and in the modification component i am applying the changes.

```
<util:XmlFile Id="ModifyConnectionString"
                     Action="setValue"
                     Permanent="no"
                     ElementPath="/configuration/connectionStrings/add[\[]@name='MigratorDB'[\]]"
                     Name="connectionString"
                     File="[INSTALLFOLDER]web.config"
                     Value='Data Source=[DB_SERVER]; Initial Catalog=[DB_DATABASE]; User Id=[MMDB_USER]; Password=[MMDB_PASSWORD];'
                     SelectionLanguage="XSLPattern"
                     Sequence="1" />
<util:XmlFile Id="Server"
                     Action="setValue"
                     Permanent="no"
                     ElementPath="/configuration/appSettings/add[\[]@key='SMTPserver'[\]]"
                     Name="value"
                     File="[INSTALLFOLDER]web.config"
                     Value='[SMTP_server]'
                     SelectionLanguage="XSLPattern"
                     Sequence="2" />
```

and same as for remaining 3 values.
but only modification is done on 'connectionstring tag'
resulted web.config is.

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="MigratorDB" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=Arslan; Initial Catalog=MailboxMigration_DB6; User Id=abc6; Password=abc;"/></connectionStrings>


<appSettings>
<add key="SMTPport" value=""/>
<add key="SMTPserver" value=""/>
<add key="EmailAddress" value=""/>
<add key="EmailPass" value=""/>
```

Comment: Could you try with SelectionLanguage="XPath"

Comment: Thanks for helping but the issue was..that the property IDs are containing lower case characters.